# The internals of NSScrollView

Tags: cocoa, draw, nsscrollview

When you gently scroll an `NSScrollView`  the rectangle that *Cocoa* marks as dirty, and passes to `drawRect`, is often trivially small (perhaps as small as one or two pixels in height, for a vertical scroll view). The framework clearly already knows what the majority of the content is (because it's on screen) and where to redraw it (just the offset brought about by the scroll), so all it needs the developer to do is fill in the small rectangle that's about to appear. I was wondering what's happening behind the scenes to allow this to happen?
For example, if I wanted to implement my own super-smooth scroll view as a learning project, what kind of data would I be recording about the document view to enable me to just re-position - rather than redraw - the majority of it. Is Cocoa constantly generating images on background threads that it draws on screen when required, or is there something a bit more subtle going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's lots going on. If you haven't already read it, you should read the [Scroll View Programming Guide for Cocoa](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/NSScrollViewGuide/Articles/Introduction.html).

The copying of the existing rendering is accomplished by `-[NSView scrollRect:by:]`. It's only done if the `NSClipView` that's part of the `NSScrollView` architecture is set to copy-on-scroll (the `copiesOnScroll` property).

Also, there's "responsive scrolling". Since 10.9, if certain conditions are met, AppKit will speculatively render the document view beyond the visible rect so that, when the user scrolls, it can show the scrolled-in area without asking the document view to render.

You can set your views to be layer-backed. In that case, they are typically rendered to textures and composited by the window server. This means they don't necessarily have to re-draw to render in a new position. It's quite likely that responsive scrolling uses layers behind the scenes to hold the pre-rendered content.